# Given a random variable $X$ and its density function $f(x),$ what is the distribution of $f(X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, density-function

[Probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#Statement) states that if a random variable $X$ has a continuous distribution for which the cumulative distribution function (CDF) is $F_X$, then $F_X(X)$ has a standard uniform distribution, that is, $F_X(X)\sim U(0,1).$

My question is about its pdf instead of cdf.

> Question: Given a random variable $X$ and its density function $f(x),$ what is the distribution of $f(X)$?

I have a feeling that $f(X)$ does not have a uniform distribution as density is the derivative of CDF. 
But I do not know what is the derivative of a uniform distribution.

Comment: Why do you say 'if any'? Every random variable has a distribution function.  There is not much you can say abut the distribution of $f(X)$. It does not have a standard distribution function in general.

Comment: For example, if $X$ follows a standard normal distribution, what is $E[f(X)]?$

Comment: I reckon the "if any" referred to the fact that the distribution may not be universal (as it was in the case with the cdf). Also, minor quibble: not every $X$ has a density to begin with.

Comment: @ClementC. In this question, we assume that density function exists.

Answer (score 2):

It is not universal, and will depend on $X$, so there is no general statement as was the case for the cdf transformation.

For instance:

- if $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, then its pdf $f$ equals $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ and $f(X) = 1$ is constant a.s.
- if $X$ is say a standard exponential distribution, then its pdf is $f(x) = e^{-x}\mathbf{1}_{x \geq 0}$ and $f(X)$ is clearly not a constant r.v.:
  $$\forall y\in[0,1],\qquad \mathbb{P}\{ f(X) \leq y \} = \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq -\log y \} = y$$

Comment: Though your standard exponential distribution has $f(X)$ neatly with a uniform distribution on $[0,1)$.  Others will not be as simple